# Что не так с тэгами в XML(SPRING)

Tags: java, xml, spring, intellij-idea

Вроде делаю все по книжке, поменял лишь на свои данные. Среда разработки ругается, тэги указаны неверно.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bean xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <bean id="song"    //bean ГОРИТ КРАСНЫМ element bean is not allowed here
          class="Spring.King" />


    <aop:config>
        <aop:aspect ref="song">
            <aop:pointcut id="s"
            expression="execution(* *.def(..))"/>

            <aop:before pointcut-ref="s"
                method="song1"/>

            <aop:after pointcut-ref="s"
                method="song2"/>
        </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>
</bean>

</beans> //UNEXPENTED TOKENS
```

Comment: class="Spring.King"  - здесь должен быть указан класс вашего бина

Comment: на второй строке в "<bean xmlns" должно быть "<beans xmlns" букву s пропустили